# how to send multiple selected values of two drop down list to ajax server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

i want to know how to send multiple values to ajax from jquery.
for example i have two drop down lists namely session ( contains monsoon, winter )
year ( contains 2010 , 2011 , 2012, 2013 , etc ). i want to send both selected values these drop down lists to ajax at time from a jquery . so please give some idea.

i tried to send single value as fallows.

```
      <body>
  <form name="frm2" method="POST">
      <table align="center" border="1">

         <tr>
            <td class="style30">

            <select  id="stream" name="current_session" >
                <option value="Winter" > Winter </option>
                <option value="Monsoon">Monsoon</option>
            </select></td>
            <td>
                <select name="year2" id="year1" style="width:200px;" >
                    <option value="2015" > 2015 </option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                    <option value="2013" > 2013 </option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                    <option value="2011" > 2011 </option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                    </select>
            </td>              
   </tr>      
   </table>                
   </form>





      <script>
     $( "#year1" ).change(function() {
     var selectedVal=$("#year1 option:selected").val();
     $.ajax({
             url:"checkonserver.jsp?given_year="+selectedVal,
       // here i sent only one selected value, 
        //but i want selected values both **sesion, year to be sent to ajax at time**.


      }
      });
      });
```

my ajax is as fallow (checkonserver.jsp)

```
 <head>


    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%=request.getParameter("given_year")%>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Send the data as a key/val pair in the `data` property of the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
     url:"checkonserver.jsp",
     data: {selectedYear : yearVariable, anotherVar : someVariable}
```

You can now access these on your backend, they are assigned to `selectedYear` and `anotherVar`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
 $( "#year1" ).change(function() {
     var year=$("#year1").val();
     var stream=$("#stream").val();
     $.ajax({
          url:"checkonserver.jsp",
          data: {selectedYear : year, stream: stream},
          error: function(){
               alert("fail!")
          },
          success: function(data){
             //data contains everything send from the server
             alert("ok")
          }

      });
  });
```

Comment: thanks sir, tell me one thing how can i ensure that these values are reached properly to ajax or not ?